# Using Zigfu in Unity3D: Method for checking if arms are raised

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner at Unity3D, C# and especially new at Kinect programming. I hoped using Zigfu would be of help for me in my project, but every time I think I understand something, I'm wrong. Since I don't actually have any code that makes sense, I'm writing this in pseudocode.

What I want to do is to check if the user has his arms raised and if so execute another method. I am using the ZigSkeleton script, and has attached the joints for hands, elbows and shoulders. I then tried writing a method in the ZigSkeleton script that was something like this; if (RightShoulder.Rotate(0, 90, -90) then return boolean ArmsRaised = true; Which did not in any way work. I then tried; if(RightElbow.Position > RightArm.Position) then boolean ArmsRaised = true;

I have realized that I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing atm, and hope someone can help me either understand and/or explain how I can write such a method.

P.S; I just need the code for a research project, so I don't really need to understand everything there is to Kinect programming (althoug a bit more than my current knowledge is probably a good idea :P)

Comment: I would really learn unity3d and c# first before trying to do kinect with it

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. However, I have done several tutorials, and have already made the rest of the game using unity and c# (and javascript). This project is for a thesis, so because of time constraints I need to focus on the actual research and not on becoming an expert in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had almost the same problem but detecting wheter or not a leg was kicking a ball. What I did is creating an empty gameobject with a collider. Something like this:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.name != "HitZone")
        return;
    //Do whatever you want here
}
```